# Adding CSS border to woocommerce product add-ons (fixing code not working with latest updates)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, add-on

I have a CSS code on an older site that add border around the Woocommerce product add-ons. (https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

You can see it here (it's the green border around the product add-ons):

https://fleuristelejolicoeur.com/produit/symphonie-de-printemps/

Now I am building a new site and with the lastest updates, the code no longer work.

Here is the code

```
/* Product Add-Ons border */

.product-addon {
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #b4cc50;
margin: 2em 0 !important;
}
    /* Product Add-Ons reduce top padding */
.single-product div.product form.cart {
    padding: 0;
}
```

When adding the code to my new site nothing happend.

I tried to modify it but with no luck.

Comment: The new site may have different layout. So you should to include the section that you want to change its border otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: Please include the html code

Answer (score 0):

I think **product-addon** class is missing in the new layout. Could you please show me the new layout?